# what is the cardinality of set $S=\{100,105,110,115,120..........995\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

what is the cardinality  of set $S=\{100,105,110,115,120..........995\}$ ?

where set S  contain the elment whose  number is  divisible  by $5$

My attempt :  I got  cardinality  of $S =210$

Is its correct ?

Is  their any  fastest   way  to  count  the  number of elements.in $S$.?

Comment: I reckon it's the same as the cardinality of $\{20,21,22,23,23,\ldots,199\}$.

Comment: You attempt is wrong. Either attempt a recount, or explain your logic so we can point out falsities.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..i  directly count the  number  its  take me  20  minutes  to counts  ,,

Comment: The elements of your set are numbers of the form $95+5k$, where $k$ starts at $1$, and ends at... Therefore, there are how many of them?

Comment: @jasmine A direct count is not required! That is probably why you went wrong. Look at the set. Can you try to come up with some shorter way of counting the elements? Look for patterns. Also see the first hint.

Comment: note that it is an arithmetic progression. Use the formula: $a_n=a_1+d(n-1) \Rightarrow 995=100+5(n-1) \Rightarrow n=?$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin...from ur  given  logics  ...i gots  180  is  Its  correct ??

Comment: @farruhota...god idea

Comment: @jasmine That is correct. Next time, before you count any set by hand, check for patterns like the one spotted in the answer below, or try to bring the problem down to counting another set which is easier to count.

Comment: oksss @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thanks !

Comment: You are welcome jasmine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$100,105,110,\cdots,995$ form an AP. So $$995=l=100+(n-1)5$$ and so $$n=180$$

Comment: thanks u @Chinnapparaj